# VHDL convert binary to hex, and hex to string

Tags: vhdl

Having a std_logic_vector how can I convert value value to HEX, and then how can I convert the hex to string?

Example: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) = "0000000001010101", HEX = 0055, and hex to string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a VHDL 2008 only operation, but in ieee.numeric_std there is a function called "to_hex_string" that takes in a std_logic_vector and outputs the hex representation as a string.

```
constant test   :   std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "00001111"; 
...
begin
...
assert false report to_hex_string(test) severity failure;
```

Otherwise, you could build your own function or try a third party package like this one : https://github.com/suoto/hdl_string_format