# Print std_logic_vector in hexadecimal (VHDL)

Tags: vhdl

I have an 8-bit std_logic_vector and I would like to print its value (during simulation) as a 2-digit hexadecimal value.

Current code:

```
report "Entity: data_in=" & integer'image(to_integer(unsigned(data_in)));
```

Current output:

```
Entity: data_in=16
```

Desired output:

```
Entity: data_in=10h
```

What would be the most painless way to achieve this?

Comment: See my answer here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/329699/vhdl-convert-binary-to-hex-and-hex-to-string/330124#330124

Comment: I wish there was something like http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ for VHDL :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In VHDL-2008, one can use:

```
report "Entity: data_in=" & to_hstring(data_in) & "h";
```